# how to show my account link in header after successfully login in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, login, customer-account, header, toplinks

[image: Homepage]
how to show my account link in header after successfully login in magento

Comment: I am Using magento custom theme.they giving 3 links create account, sign in and my account. i would like to show my account after successfully log-in.

Comment: Duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124878/how-can-i-check-whether-user-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i check whether user is logged in or not in magento 2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124878/how-can-i-check-whether-user-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2-0)

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code to show your account link in header:

```
<?php
    $objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    $baseurl = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl();
?>
    <?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $baseurl .'customer/account/logout'; ?>">LOGOUT</a>
    <?php }else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $baseurl .'customer/account/login'; ?>">LOGIN</a>       
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: could you specify the folder path and file name to put this code..

Comment: This is not working as expected since it creating cache issue,after login it will always show login link on home page.

Comment: Bad form to use the object manager directly, inject the session dependency into your block.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the places where Magento does this already. If you take a look at the customer modules default.xml:

**vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

You will see a call to the code that creates the sign in link:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
           template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

I'm pointing out the `AuthorizationLink` class in this code. This makes a call to a template file that has the logic that fills in the conditions for having a link that changes based on if the user is logged in or not.

```
/** @var $block \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink */
$dataPostParam = '';
if ($block->isLoggedIn()) {
    $dataPostParam = sprintf(" data-post='%s'", $block->getPostParams());
}
?>
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('or')); ?>">
    <a <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLinkAttributes(); ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $dataPostParam; ?>>
        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()); ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

While is isn't exactly what you are looking to do (magento always does it's work in the most convoluted way possible), it's a way in the theme to add in blocks that call in templates that will do the kind of work you are looking for.

Comment: I know that it's coming from there but i'm not getting answer.

Comment: There is no way for anyone without that theme to help you with the exact code that you need to get this functionality. The theme is creating a block or container in it's xml for those links, using that block or container to hook into and add your link is the only way to get a template in there that does what you want. Most likely the file driving that is `{{theme}}/Magneto_Theme/layout/default.xml` but this only a guess.

Comment: @circlesix Do you know how the authorization.phtml will call firstly and check that customer is logged in or not?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example block:

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Links extends Template
{
    /** @var Url $_customerUrl */
    protected $_customerUrl;

    /** @var Context $httpContext */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Links constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param Url $customerUrl
     * @param Context $httpContext
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
                                Url $customerUrl,
                                Context $httpContext,
                                array $data)
    {
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Is logged in
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }

    /**
     * Get account URL
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccountUrl()
    {
        return $this->_customerUrl->getAccountUrl();
    }
}
```

And how you might call it from template:

```
<ul class="header links">
    <?php if ($block->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $block->getAccountUrl() ?>">
            <?php echo __('My Account') ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you but i'm working on magento 2

Comment: This is magento 2 code.

Comment: As i am new to  magento 2.0 . could you please assist me through live example..I'm not getting  @Aaron

Comment: You'll have to create a simple module. The tutorial here http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc will give you the tools to implement this. You'll just need the block, template, and a default.xml layout file to position the block.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the backend to redirect the customer to his dashboard page after logging in.
Look for it in `System->Configuration->Customer configuration`.

Comment: did you posted an answer before question posted ?

Comment: I am not getting. Actually i am using custom theme  which having 3 links my account  ,create account and sign in. but i want to show my account after successfully login. @BabyinMagento

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2, when you sign In then create an account link is already gone.

I hope this helps..

Regards
Gaurav