# How can i check whether user is logged in or not in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, login

How can I check whether user is logged in or not in Magento 2.0 
I using `phtml` file I want to check user logged in or not.

```
<span class="selllink switcher top-links">
    <span class="" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome,%1').replace('%1', customer().firstname) : '<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
    </span>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</span>
```

Comment: You mention "using phtml file". If you want to hack the code into any PHTML template and not use or create a block class that gives you access to this specific information, refer to one of the "Object Manager" answers of the linked duplicate. If you are willing to take the extra effort and go for a clean solution, please update your question with more information: which template, which block, how do you use it?

Comment: ### [Similarily: How can i check whether user is logged in or not in magento 2 &#187;](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score -7, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');


if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    // do your code
}
```

Comment: It's working but username not showing on aws. @RJ07

Comment: Why this is marked as solution when it's not working. And again creating new instance of the object manager in template file. Check out my answer and the comments below. Other thing is that you are trying to display the username with knockoutJS variable which is out of the question scope.

Comment: We should never use direct object managers in any class.

Answer (score 23):

To check if customer is loged in or not you can call **Magento\Customer\Model\Session::isLoggedIn()** method.

If you want to do that properly in *.phtml files you should use helper inside the template. Object manager is not preferred way to call models inside template files. So I am not recommending to follow [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)
There isn't core helper that can be reused so you need to create new one.

```
<?php
namespace YourCompany\ModuleName\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Then in your *.phtml file you can call your helper and call isLoggedIn method like this:

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('YourCompany\ModuleName\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php if($helper->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
    logged in
<?php else : ?>
    not logged in
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes It's Working.

Comment: When i deployed on AWS server it is not working.

Comment: What you mean by "not working" Be more specific. Do you have enabled caches? Try to set cacheable="false" for your block in the layout xml file

Comment: Yes it's working but username is not showing now. @Miroslav Petroff

Comment: Can you show your code and how you are displaying the username

Comment: locally it is showing but on AWS it's not showing,edited  post and added code @Miroslav Petroff

Comment: without using helper and data file it's working @Miroslav Petroff

Comment: Also the cart will not clear after logout.

Comment: This is not related with your initial question and my answer. Also I am not responsible for your problem with showing customer's username. You are using knockoutJS template. The problem is different and you voted down my answer because of your other problems.

Comment: On me is not working for all pages, for example if I am on /customer/ page is working, if not, then it always display "not logged in" on Magento 2.1

Comment: This worked for me. The trick was to add `cacheable="false"` at the block level in layout XML.

Comment: thanks. this is working. Learnt about Helpers in Magento

Answer (score 5):

This is for only Magento 2.0, add this in `phtml` file:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
```

Check via following:

```
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get user logged in at template level phtml, you can call :

```
<?php $_loggedin = $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCart()->getCustomerSession()->isLoggedIn(); ?>
```

Comment: Good call if you don't want to rewrite whole blocks for a mundane template in the theme!

Answer (score 2):

You can also check with below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $customerSession->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

    if($isLoggedIn){
        // Logged In
    }else{
        // Not Logged In
    }
```

Comment: That solution is working for me on all pages Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must call object in magento 2 for custom coding in any page.
so code will look like this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){

//Code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am try to get the logged in condition on header.phtml file with above helper  code in custom module app/code/venter/ module name/ helper/Data.php
Actually my concerns is thats i want to restrict all the categories products page cms page from the frontend if any frontend users are not logged in it will not access any pages except home page.where we apply the code.please anyone help me

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function isLoggedIn()
{
    return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
}
```

}