# Checking if customer is logged in only working on account pages

Tags: magento2, php, customer-account, user

So, I followed the steps in the 2nd answer (by Miroslav Petroff) on this question: [How can i check whether user is logged in or not in magento 2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124878/how-can-i-check-whether-user-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2-0)

The if statement only works correctly when viewing pages like Wishlist, My Account, Cart, etc. Currently on the Homepage, Catalog pages, Product pages, and possibly others, my if statement is returning 'not-logged-in'.

```
if ( $helper->isLoggedIn() ):
echo ' logged-in';
else:
echo ' not-logged-in';
endif;
```

Anyone ideas what might make these pages return different results?

Comment: Maybe you should try the alternative solution I provide in this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125519/2380

Comment: Are you sure those pages are not being cached? You'll have to mark any blocks that use your helper as uncachable.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this answer and now the if statement returns the correct value on all pages.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108478/40091

Everyone says not to call the ObjectManager directly, but sometimes you gotta live life on the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
{
// your code
}
```