# How to show My Account link in frontend after succesfully logged in?

Tags: magento2.3, header, toplinks, myaccount

How can I show the My Account in header after the welcome message after successfully logged in my website?

I have got help in displaying them on customer menu but now I want to show it in header instead of customer menu.

Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You want to add My account link after this ? **Welcom, sivakumar n!    My Account    Log Out**. Something like this ?

Comment: Yes @KishanSavaliya. I want to display it after the customer logged in

Comment: Plz review this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add this line in your `default.xml` file

```
<move element="my-account-link" destination="mycustom4.div" after="header.links" />
```

After adding this line you need to make some CSS changes there.

**Another solution**

If you do not need **My Account** link for `Guest user` then you can use below code.

Add this lines in your `default.xml` file

```
<referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />

<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link-custom" after="header.links" template="Magento_Theme::header/myaccount_custom.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

And Create one Block file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Account/Link.php

Content for this file is ...

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface;

class Link extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link
{
    protected $_customerUrl;
    protected $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $customerUrl, $data);
    }

    public function getIsCustomerLoggedIn(){
        return $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }
}
```

And you need to add template file here..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/header/myaccount_custom.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<?php if($block->getIsCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $block->getHref(); ?>"><?php echo __("My Account"); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After changing this please run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks. But it will display the My Account link even though user not logged in the site. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, Right that link will appear when customer is not logged in.

Comment: I wanted it display after customer logged in and it should not visible before login.

Comment: Okay sending you file from where that is coming so you can add login, not login condition there.

Comment: I've updated my answer please review that and you can accept my answer and an upvote if that will works for you! Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please confirm the path where I have to create a Block file?

Comment: @Siva, You can create new module or if you have any existing custom module then you can add that file there.

Comment: Is that helpful ?

Comment: Working on this and update you the status once done.

Comment: Okay Let me know

Comment: Last day, I have asked a question and updated now with screenshot. Please have a look at it https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293257/magento2-3-how-to-create-separate-myaccount-dashboard

Comment: Okay sure. I'll check.

Comment: Please do approve my answers, If that are helpful to you! And also give me an upvote. Thanks :)

Comment: I have tried this by creating a new module and getting the below error Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::header/myaccount_custom.phtml' in module: 'Butterfly_Myaccount' block's name: 'my-account-link-custom'.

Comment: **Magento_Theme::header/myaccount_custom.phtml**, Please send me this file's path

Comment: The file path is /app/design/frontend/Butterfly/Mssr/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/myaccount_custom.phtml

Comment: Please move your file here.. **app/design/frontend/Butterfly/Mssr/Magento_Theme/templates/header/myaccount_custom.phtml** and then clear cache and check.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will do it and let you know.

Comment: I have updated as per your suggestion and working great now! Thanks

Comment: You're most welcome. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100232/discussion-on-answer-by-kishan-savaliya-how-to-show-my-account-link-in-frontend).